# Перерисовка QTableView при скроллировании

Tags: c++, qt

Нужен виджет, который будет рисоваться поверх `QTableView`. Если этому виджету при создании указать парентом `QTableView` или виджет, в котором он лежит, то при скроллировании `QTableView` наблюдается полная перерисовка `QTableView`. Если указать парентом `viewport`, то перерисовка происходит как если бы этого виджета не было. Есть какие-то мысли по поводу того, как этого избежать?

Answer (score 1):

попробуй указать парент после создания `QTableView`